# is there a way to delete data from a firebase real time database (using flutter) after 1 day?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add data that stays in the database for 1 day by default and then get deleted. Unless I set a different time (more than one day).

Comment: This question has very little detail but I would say that you should look at using a Firebase cloud function to achieve that. There is no RTDB mechanism that does it.

Comment: you can use firebase cloud function to do that task.

Comment: I thought I just said that 

Answer (score 0):

You can create something like below method and you need to upload that on Firebase Cloud Function

const CUT_OFF_TIME = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 2 Hours in milliseconds.

```
exports.deleteOldMessages = functions.database.ref('[path]').onWrite(async (change) => {
    const ref = change.after.ref.parent; // reference to the parent
    const now = Date.now();
    const cutoff = (now - CUT_OFF_TIME) / 1000; // convert to seconds
    const oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('seconds').endAt(cutoff);
    const snapshot = await oldItemsQuery.once('value');
    // create a map with all children that need to be removed
    const updates = {};
    snapshot.forEach(child => {
        updates[child.key] = null;
    });
    // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
    return ref.update(updates);
});
```

You can checkout below link for reference as well.

[souce](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIpumcl6ft-wIVisDICh3eNAjWEAAYASAAEgIbZvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)